# Firebug internal error message

Tags: firebug, internal

I'm using Firefox: 3.5 and Firebug: 1.4.0.b3

On my local Ethernet site I am getting an error message in my firebug console:

```
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80540006 
    [nsIStreamListener.onDataAvailable]"  nsresult: "0x80540006 (<unknown>)"  
    location: "JS frame :: file:///Users/max/Library/Application%20Support/Firefox/Profiles/e5cfamop.default/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com/components/firebug-channel-listener.js :: anonymous :: line 107"  data: no]
file:///Users/max/Library/Application%20Support/Firefox/Profiles/e5cfamop.default/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com/components/firebug-channel-listener.js
Line 107
```

Has someone seen that before?

Thx Max

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Firefox team have fixed this bug - upgrade to the latest version of Firefox to resolve the issue.